# Number of different possible solution to an equation in java

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, math

I need to find the number of total possible different solution to an equation with more than one variable.

For example:

```
1x + 2y + 8z = 13
```

What is the total number of different combinations for the values of x, y and z?
I can't think of an algorithm to solve this. I don't need the answers printed, just the total number of different combinations. The coefficients and variables will always be positive, and the final number too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for Mathematics SE!

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful, I don't think so, I need an algorythm to solve this, that's why I posted here...

Comment: @FelipeRibeiroR.Magalhaes the problem is that SO is not a coding service. Think of an approach and ask questions about specifc problems.

Comment: This is not a coding question. Figure out how to solve it on paper, then write the equivalent in code.

Comment: I think it can be solved easily by dynamic programming. Approach of @JoopEggen would be too slow for bigger numbers.

Answer (score 5):

```
1x + 2y + 8z = 13
```

Hence try (x, y,z) from (0, 0, 0) upto  (13, 6, 1)
Hence at most 14*7*2 tries

Sort by the highest coefficient: z, y, x. The last variable can be inferred

Comment: Interesting approach, will try it and see if the perfomance is reasonable.